# Is there such thing as a tunable DC/DC converter?

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

Note: I am not an electrical engineer.  I am quite removed from the field so please bear with me.

I have run into some electrical modelling projects which suggest that a DC/DC converter can be used to tune voltage to pretty much whatever they please. As power fluctuates with time, they assume that the voltage can be modulated accordingly.

I have never come across a DC/DC converter technology that has a tunable voltage. Usually, it is set, and the current is changed to whatever to adapt. Am I mistaken? Do feedback DC/DC converters exist?

Preliminary search suggests that there may be some research-grade versions of a [similar technology](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7993625).  I am  not sure if this is the same thing, and if commercially viable approach exists.

Edit: It seems I am using the incorrect terminology (which is partly what I am seeking clarification on). Yes, adjustable voltage systems are what I am looking for -- not a regulator as pointed out.

No, I need to regulate voltage in this case because I am analyzing an experimental electrolyzer rather than a max product problem. I appreciate everyone's input. The specific applications are not so important, I am more interested in the existence of an adjustable voltage system, and its limitations.

Comment: Any lab DC/DC power supply will do what you ask.

Comment: Please explain better what you mean by "tunable voltage". The question wording suggests that you don't' mean merely variable output voltage that can be tuned by a knob or something. Or you do?

Comment: Do they exist in larger scale, lets say, for fluctuation power supply from a PV.

Comment: Lets say I have a load attached to a PV. I then need to change the voltage depending on fluctuations in solar intensity accordingly to math the load.

Comment: Change how? Manually? What is PV? Many of DC/DC converters are either variable output or have some grade of fine-tuning (set voltage that can be tuned plus/minus few percent).

Comment: A DC/DC voltage regulator that couldn't handle variations in the input voltage would be rather useless.  All DC/DC voltage regulators have a voltage range that they can accept.  Many have a fixed output voltage.  There are also very many that have an adjustable output voltage.  Since you are looking specifically at photovoltaic systems, there are regulator modules that can adapt the current they draw from the solar cells so as to get the maximum power from the panels.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: The suggest (the person I talked to about this), that a software would adjust the voltage so it works for the load that is being attached. When you say variable output, meaning you could in theory change it to whatever voltage you require? (PV = photovoltaic cell)

Comment: @JRE thank you for this information. Yes, I am looking for adjustable output voltages that would be potentially regulated via software.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Use an MPPT to output power from a solar cell, but adjust the voltage accordingly as to match the Power voltage function of the load.

Comment: What is your load?

Comment: Hydrogen electrolyzer.

Comment: Then you'll want to control the current.  [Speed of production is proportional to the current.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolysis#Process_of_electrolysis)  There are DC/DC converters that can regulate the current rather than the voltage.

Comment: From the comments so far, since you mentioned MPPT, it seems you want do maximize the hydrogen production (maximum current) for any condition of the photovoltaic cell. Is this correct?

Comment: Constraining MPPT further by asking for adjustable voltage too? Seems like one-too -many constraints. Either max power **OR** variable-voltage.

Comment: Since the question you're asking really has nothing to do with what you want answered, I'm voting to close until the question is fixed. Otherwise you're just going to get a bunch of unhelpful answers.

Comment: Damn, I just finished a long answer, can we reopen it?

Comment: @user1850749 my question should not concern my specific application, I just provided it since it was asked. The explanation of adjustable voltage systems has answered my question sufficiently.

Comment: Please explain the difference the difference between a “voltage system” and a (voltage) regulator from here: _”Yes, adjustable voltage systems are what I am looking for -- not a regulator as pointed out.”_ Even after your update, it sounds like you need a normal CC/CV lab supply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be confusing two things: Voltage regulation, and adjustable output.

Any circuit sold as a "voltage regulator" should adjust its behavior to provide the same output voltage when its input voltage changes. It will also adjust its output current as needed to maintain the same output voltage when the load current changes. These two features are what the "regulator" part of the name means.

Such circuits are very common, but the specific design will depend on the output voltage and current required, how accurate the output power must be, etc.

That's an entirely different requirement than what your text asks for, which is an adjustable output voltage. This is also fairly widely available, and is usually done by adjusting the feedback ratio in the control loop of the voltage regulator. It is a bit trickier to design than a fixed-output voltage regulator because you must ensure stability of the control loop at any setting of the output voltage.

In comments you said that your application is a hydrogen electrolyzer. In this case you probably don't want a voltage regulator at all, but a constant current supply, so the specific questions you're asking and their answers don't really apply to your application. That said, constant current supplies are also widely available, and again the specific design will depend on your specific requirements.